# requirejs data-main vs require loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

What is the difference between this snippets in the **index.html** file ?

```
<script src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>

<script>
    require(['myModule/require']);
</script>
```

and

```
<script data-main="myModule/require" src="lib/requirejs/require.js">/script>
<script src="myModule/require.js"></script>
```